# how to export/import managed properties and mapping to align them accross environments

Tags: 2013, search, powershell, managed-property

I have backed up a content db from prod to dev environments.

Everything works fine, but I noticed the managed properties are not aligned across environments
Obviosly I dont want to do this manually so I want to know if its possible with powershell to export the managed properties + mappings and configuration and then import that configuration in a different farm.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At both the Site and Site Collection level in SharePoint 2013 you can Import/Export the Search Configuration. If you are moving from Farm to Farm the Content Sources configured in the Search SA need to be at least similar (if not the same) so that your Crawled Properties are available for mapping. You can use PowerShell to export the Crawled Properties and Managed Properties from the SSA. (There is no Export option in the SSA).

Look at the SearchConfigurationPortability class.

[Import and Export Search Configuration](http://andersrask.sharepointspace.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=42)

Comment: please let me know how to do this with powershell then

Comment: Have you searched for an answer> I found the above.