# How to create a SharePoint Search Result Item Type programmatically?

Tags: search, search-results, display-template, result-types

I have a requirement to update the Display Template for a given content type, I do understand that Display template can be deployed and published through "Feature activation".

However, I see that New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType is the only way to create a Result Item Type.

I want to put everything under the "Feature activation". How do I create a SharePoint Search Result Item Type programmatically?

Comment: Have you looked at importing a Search Configuration?

Comment: No, can you please explain. Note I want to put everything in the solution package that way none really have to configure anything manually.

Comment: Check this answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89530/how-to-export-import-managed-properties-and-mapping-to-align-them-accross-enviro